# Yii Framework CDetailView "No set" label

Tags: yii, cdetailview

When there is no any data in one column the words "No set" are displayed, i want to change this message but i don't know where o how to do it, i have try extending CDetailView but it didn't work, any sggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
array(
  'attributeName1',
  'attributeName2',
)
```

when defining the data to display in your detail view, use

```
array(
  array(
    'label'=>'Whatever you want',
    'value'=>null===$model->attributeName1?
      "custom message":
      $model->attributeName1,
  ),
  'attributeName2',
)
```

This gives you the power to format the content however you want it.